# Make it so lists can go through the function

Tags: python, function, iteration

```
for url in indexurls:
    row = parseFormPage(indexurls)
row
```

`indexurls` is a list filled with urls

returns an error instead of going through the list.
Need help with iterations!
heres the function code

```
def parseFormPage(indexurls):
    '''
    Input: URL

    Output:
        filer_cik:
        filing_date:
        report_date:
        form_url
    '''

    # get page and create soup
    res = requests.get(indexurls)
    html = res.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    # parse filer Info on 10K page
    filer_div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'filerDiv'})
    filer_text = filer_div.find('span', {'class': 'companyName'}).find('a').get_text()
    filer_cik = re.search(r"(\d{10})\s(\(.+\))$" ,filer_text)[1]

    # parse 10K Page Meta data
    form_content = soup.find('div', {'class': 'formContent'})

    filing_date = form_content.find('div', text='Filing Date').findNext('div').get_text()
    report_date = form_content.find('div', text='Period of Report').findNext('div').get_text()

    # parse 10-K URL
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tableFile', 'summary': 'Document Format Files'})
    href = table.find('td', text='10-K').find_parent('tr').find('a')['href']
    form_url = "https://www.sec.gov" + href

    return filer_cik, filing_date, report_date, form_url
```

the error is below

this is what the error is below, i think its more an issue with the list?

```
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1599407/0001477932-16-009759-index.htm']
```

this a sample : `https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1599407/0001477932-16-009759-index.htm`

and expected output should be a list of :

```
('0001606163',
 '2016-03-21',
 '2015-12-31',
 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1606163/000114420416089184/v434424_10k.htm')
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample url and the expected output from that?

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: `requests.get` takes one URL but you're passing it a list. Is that the problem?

Comment: I think that may be it, is there to make it so lists can go through it ?

Comment: @wjandrea is probably right; if you have your filings' urls in a list, just create a loop: drop the function definition, and do something like `for url in indexurls:  res = requests.get(url)` or something along these lines.

Comment: @skududu I'll post an answer.

Comment: @wjandrea You guys are amazing thank you! Just one last issue im having, im still getting the error about the connection adapter. How would i go about removing the [' '] from the urls.

Comment: @skududu Welcome! Your sample doesn't have the `'['` ... `']` so maybe it's related to the list? I mean `['...']` is a list containing a string. If you can't figure it out, please ask a new question with a [mre]. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

`requests.get` takes one URL but you're passing it a list. Is that the problem?

To fix it you would change the loop:

```
for url in indexurls:
    row = parseFormPage(url)
```

Plus rename the function parameter:

```
def parseFormPage(indexurl):
    ...
    res = requests.get(indexurl)
    ...
```